# AJAX call returning "Unexpected token <"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

So here's what's going on.

I've got an AJAX call that's supposed to be returning an array of JSON objects.

The AJAX call looks like this:

```
ajax : function( url , data,  success ){

        return $.ajax( {
                    url      : url,
                    type     : 'POST',
                    data     : data,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success  : function( data ){ success( data ); },
                    error    : function( jqXHR , textStatus , errorThrown )
                    {
                        console.log( errorThrown );
                    }
                } );
    }
```

the invocation of that function is this:

```
this.tvModelsAjax = this.ajax( sanus_website_search.tvModelAutocomplete,
                                        {q : autoCompleteController.query },
                                        autoCompleteController.success );
```

And the returned data looks like this, if you open it in a browser:

```
[{"name":"SAMSUNG 40\" 400BX","url":"\/app_dev.php\/en_US\/mountfinder\/SAMSUNG\/40%22\/400BX\/results\/"},{"name":"SAMSUNG 40\" 400CX","url":"\/app_dev.php\/en_US\/mountfinder\/SAMSUNG\/40%22\/400CX\/results\/"},{"name":"SAMSUNG 40\" 400CX1","url":"\/app_dev.php\/en_US\/mountfinder\/SAMSUNG\/40%22\/400CX1\/results\/"},{"name":"SAMSUNG 40\" 400CX2","url":"\/app_dev.php\/en_US\/mountfinder\/SAMSUNG\/40%22\/400CX2\/results\/"},{"name":"SAMSUNG 40\" 400CXN","url":"\/app_dev.php\/en_US\/mountfinder\/SAMSUNG\/40%22\/400CXN\/results\/"},{"name":"SAMSUNG 40\" 400CXN1","url":"\/app_dev.php\/en_US\/mountfinder\/SAMSUNG\/40%22\/400CXN1\/results\/"},{"name":"SAMSUNG 40\" 400CXN2","url":"\/app_dev.php\/en_US\/mountfinder\/SAMSUNG\/40%22\/400CXN2\/results\/"},{"name":"SAMSUNG 40\" 400DX","url":"\/app_dev.php\/en_US\/mountfinder\/SAMSUNG\/40%22\/400DX\/results\/"},{"name":"SAMSUNG 40\" 400DX2","url":"\/app_dev.php\/en_US\/mountfinder\/SAMSUNG\/40%22\/400DX2\/results\/"},{"name":"SAMSUNG 40\" 400DX3","url":"\/app_dev.php\/en_US\/mountfinder\/SAMSUNG\/40%22\/400DX3\/results\/"}]
```

But jQuery is throwing an error telling me I have an unexpected "<" token somewhere...I'm at a loss.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's jQuery throwing the error? Does the error still come up if you don't run or comment out the ajax statement?

Comment: It sounds like your request is returning HTML (hence the unrecognised `<`). My guess would be a server error. Have you checked the actual returned value of the request in a DOM inspector?

Comment: When you open the returned data in browser... do right click and view source. Probably there is HTML in there which you cannot see because it was rendered and you are thinking its only my data.

Comment: @G_M, I don't get the error if I comment out the ajax call.
RoryMcCrossan, I suppose that's possible. If I inspect the response in Chrome, it's wrapped in a <pre> block, but I'm guessing that's just chrome imposing some rules...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, after checking in FF View Source, there's nothing but the JSON data in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks,

Seems like the PHP I was querying against was expecting GET method, not POST like the rest of the calls on that page. I ended up adding a 'method' parameter to the ajax method. Results below. Thanks for your help!

ajax : function( url , data,  success, method = 'POST' ){

```
    return $.ajax( {
                url      : url,
                type     : method,
                data     : data,
                dataType : 'json',
                success  : function( data ){ success( data ); },
                error    : function( jqXHR , textStatus , errorThrown )
                {
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
            } );
}
```